# Creating a WAR file from multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a simple project with following structure:

```
myApp - parent pom
|-app - REST API module
|-db - JDBI module
```

I want these two to stay as they are and add a third module from which I will be able to create a war. Also, my app module is a REST API created using Dropwizard. I read that I should create in new module a WEBINF catalog with web.xml, but I don't know what do I put in there.

Are there any example projects, tutorials, links or references how to do it? I'm new to maven and Java EE.

Comment: This may help - http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Comment: You have to tell us what myApp, app and do is actually? Is it one project? Or should be myApp your parent project?

Comment: MyApp is a patent pom. App is a REST API Application, and db is JDBI connection module

Comment: Does your "app" module has dependency on db module in pom.xml? If so, I think it's enough to create WAR file from "app" module - why do you think you need another module?

Comment: Ok, I can do this, but still - how to do it? Adding just `<packaging>war</packaging>` doesn't work, because i don't have web.xml. (REST API made by Dropwizard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. It's [wizard-in-a-box](https://github.com/rvs-fluid-it/wizard-in-a-box) project that do all the necessary things to build a WAR file.